# Need help for the example on conjugation.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

This is an example from Dummit & Foote text, i've some queries in this-

If $|G|>1$, then unlike action by left multiplication,$G$ does not act tranistively on itself by conjugation because {1} is always a conjugacy class (i.e., an orbit for the action).More generally,the one element subset {a} is a conjugacy class iff $gag^{-1}=a$ and for all $g \in G $ iff  $a$ is in the centre of $G$.

My questions are-

- Does here $|G|>1$ refers to order of non-abelian group?
- What is meant by  "unlike action by left multiplication"?What if here 'unlike' is replaced by 'like' ?

Please help me in answering these questions & explain this example with authentic statements and specific example.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$|G|$ refers to the order of $G$ (abelian or not). Action by left multiplication is always transitive (consequence of the so-called 'sudoku property' of groups). The conjugation action however, is not transitive for any non-trivial group $G$.

Comment: :Does here  'left multiplication'  refers to simple group composition?

Comment: It refers to the *left* group action defined by the group's multiplication operation. A group action is a map $G\times X \rightarrow X$ satisfying certain properties. In this case the set $X$ is none other than the set of the group $G$, and the action of a $g\in G$ on an $x \in X$ is none other than $g.x=g\star x$. (the action of $g$ on $x$ is the same as taking the product in $G$ of $g$ and $x$ with $g$ on the left).

Comment: @thanks for help!

Comment: Is there any notion of 'right group action'?Why books mostly exaggerate only on left group action ?

Comment: There is, but whenever you have a *right* group action, there is an equivalent *left* group action, hence you can considerably simplify notation, conventions, and language, by sticking exclusively with left actions. The map that expresses the equivalence is any anti-automorphism from $G$ to $G^{op}$ from the group $G$ to it's opposite group $G^{op}$ (e.g. the group theory example here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antihomomorphism). Edit: also mentioned here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action

Comment: This page details the map I mentioned: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opposite_group